# Create and Edit components written same but only one routes back to home page

Tags: reactjs, components, mern

I have a MERN stack project. Problem is `Edit.js` routes back to the home page but the `Create.js` file does not. No error message, it just reloads page to empty state and doesn't route back to home page. Included App.js, Edit.js, Create.js

App.js:

'''

```
import React from "react";

// We use Route in order to define the different routes of our application
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

// We import all the components we need in our app
import Navbar from "./components/navbar";
import Edit from "./components/edit";
import Create from "./components/create";
import RecordList from "./components/recordList";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Route exact path="/">
        <RecordList />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} />
      <Route path="/create" >
        <Create />
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

'''

After calling `Axios.post` `this.props.history.push("/");` routes back home in
`Edit.js`:

'''

```
// Imports, construtcor, get record based on id from db, state props updates, function to handle submission w/ axios, and the update form for inputs.
import React,  { Component }  from "react";
// This will require to npm install axios
import axios from "axios";
//import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Edit extends Component {
  // This is the constructor that stores the data.
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangePersonName = this.onChangePersonName.bind(this);
    this.onChangePersonPosition = this.onChangePersonPosition.bind(this);
    this.onChangePersonLevel = this.onChangePersonLevel.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      person_name: "",
      person_position: "",
      person_level: "",
      records: [],
    };
  }
//   This will get the record based on the id from the database.
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://employee-app-mern.herokuapp.com/record/" + this.props.match.params.id)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          person_name: response.data.person_name,
          person_position: response.data.person_position,
          person_level: response.data.person_level,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  // These methods will update the state properties.
  onChangePersonName(e) {
    this.setState({
      person_name: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangePersonPosition(e) {
    this.setState({
      person_position: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangePersonLevel(e) {
    this.setState({
      person_level: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  // This function will handle the submission.
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newEditedperson = {
      person_name: this.state.person_name,
      person_position: this.state.person_position,
      person_level: this.state.person_level,
    };
    console.log(newEditedperson);

    // This will send a post request to update the data in the database.
    axios
      .post("https://employee-app-mern.herokuapp.com/update/" + this.props.match.params.id, newEditedperson)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }

  // This following section will display the update-form that takes the input from the user to update the data.
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 align="center">Update Record</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Person's Name: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.person_name}
              onChange={this.onChangePersonName}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Position: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.person_position}
              onChange={this.onChangePersonPosition}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input
                className="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="priorityOptions"
                id="priorityLow"
                value="Intern"
                checked={this.state.person_level === "Intern"}
                onChange={this.onChangePersonLevel}
              />
              <label className="form-check-label">Intern</label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input
                className="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="priorityOptions"
                id="priorityMedium"
                value="Associate"
                checked={this.state.person_level === "Associate"}
                onChange={this.onChangePersonLevel}
              />
              <label className="form-check-label">Associate</label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input
                className="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="priorityOptions"
                id="priorityHigh"
                value="Senior"
                checked={this.state.person_level === "Senior"}
                onChange={this.onChangePersonLevel}
              />
              <label className="form-check-label">Senior</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />

          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Update Record"
              className="btn btn-primary"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// You can get access to the history object's properties and the closest <Route>'s match via the withRouter
// higher-order component. This makes it easier for us to edit our records.

export default Edit
```

'''

Create.js:

'''

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
// This will require to npm install axios
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

export default class Create extends Component {
  // This is the constructor that stores the data.
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangePersonName = this.onChangePersonName.bind(this);
    this.onChangePersonPosition = this.onChangePersonPosition.bind(this);
    this.onChangePersonLevel = this.onChangePersonLevel.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      person_name: "",
      person_position: "",
      person_level: "",
    };
  }

  // These methods will update the state properties.
  onChangePersonName(e) {
    this.setState({
      person_name: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangePersonPosition(e) {
    this.setState({
      person_position: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangePersonLevel(e) {
    this.setState({
      person_level: e.target.value,
    });
  }

// This function will handle the submission.
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // When post request is sent to the create url, axios will add a new record(newperson) to the database.
    const newperson = {
      person_name: this.state.person_name,
      person_position: this.state.person_position,
      person_level: this.state.person_level,
    };

    axios
      .post("https://employee-app-mern.herokuapp.com/record/add", newperson)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));

    // We will empty the state after posting the data to the database
        this.setState({
          person_name: "",
          person_position: "",
          person_level: "",
        });
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }

  // This following section will display the form that takes the input from the user.
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <h3>Create New Record</h3>
        <h6>Click top left "MongoDataBase" button to return and see your new entry.</h6>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Name of the person: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.person_name}
              onChange={this.onChangePersonName}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Person's position: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.person_position}
              onChange={this.onChangePersonPosition}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input
                className="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="priorityOptions"
                id="priorityLow"
                value="Intern"
                checked={this.state.person_level === "Intern"}
                onChange={this.onChangePersonLevel}
              />
              <label className="form-check-label">Intern</label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input
                className="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="priorityOptions"
                id="priorityMedium"
                value="Associate"
                checked={this.state.person_level === "Associate"}
                onChange={this.onChangePersonLevel}
              />
              <label className="form-check-label">Associate</label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input
                className="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="priorityOptions"
                id="priorityHigh"
                value="Senior"
                checked={this.state.person_level === "Senior"}
                onChange={this.onChangePersonLevel}
              />
              <label className="form-check-label">Senior</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Create person"
              className="btn btn-primary"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//export default (Create)
```

'''

Here, `this.props.history.push("/");` is called after emptying the state of create component but it does not route back to the home page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any error messages? What debugging have you done? Think you could provide a more complete and comprehensive code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There's no error message since the create page just reloads to an empty state after creating a user. I'm gathering more of the code now, will post soon for more details.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I Added full App.js, Edit.js, Create.js. Idk if it is relevant, but at some point I tried adding 'export default (Create)' to the end of Create.js, same as there is in Edit.js, and I got the error message: "src/components/create.js
  Line 142:  Parsing error: Only one default export allowed per module. (142:0)" so I commented that out.
Here is the live website: "https://employee-app-mern.herokuapp.com" @DrewReese

Comment: Right, only need one default export per file. Still have an issue with navigating/routing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what was going on: when I got the error message "Only one default export allowed per module" I didn't notice there are two calls to default inside Create.js:
Beginning - export default class Create extends Component
End - export default (Create)

I assumed it referred to default being called in Edit.js and in Create.js so I deleted it "export default (Create)" and the call to "/" was still not being executed because I was deleting the wrong default.

Solution: Delete "default" from "export default class Create extends Component" statement. The app now successfully calls "/" and routes back to the home page.

'''

```
export default class Create extends Component {
  // This is the constructor that stores the data.
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
```

'''

becomes:

'''

```
export class Create extends Component {
  // This is the constructor that stores the data.
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
```

'''

*notice default no longer called after export